# Command errored out with exit status 1 on mac while installing odoo

Tags: macos, odoo-13

command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/d1/qbs5yr054qb2w8kk6dmwzz9r0000gn/T/pip-install-cu02imcv/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; _file='"'"'/private/var/folders/d1/qbs5yr054qb2w8kk6dmwzz9r0000gn/T/pip-install-cu02imcv/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(file);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, _*file*, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
cwd: /private/var/folders/d1/qbs5yr054qb2w8kk6dmwzz9r0000gn/T/pip-install-cu02imcv/psycopg2/
Complete output (23 lines):
running egg_info
creating pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info
writing pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

```
Error: pg_config executable not found.

pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
option:

    python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
'psycopg2-binary' package instead.

For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
<http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html>).

----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: In the future also put an actual question instead of just the error message. People will downvote you.

Answer (score 0):

install pg_config first and then try again.

Run this brew command first:

```
brew install postgresql
```

Then reinstall again.