# Why do I get this error when installing ZS library Python? ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: command: path/python -u -c 'import sys,

Tags: python, installation, pip

i am installing ZS library (https://zs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/logistics.html) in Python with the command --> **pip install zs** but I'm always getting this error as result:

command: /Users/user/opt/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/86/rclj3l7x7jg9fz8pxnwqx3fw0000gn/T/pip-install-y6w6o5s6/zs_df7e592a69884a79a9c736d8120cade7/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/private/var/folders/86/rclj3l7x7jg9fz8pxnwqx3fw0000gn/T/pip-install-y6w6o5s6/zs_df7e592a69884a79a9c736d8120cade7/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/86/rclj3l7x7jg9fz8pxnwqx3fw0000gn/T/pip-wheel-s4vvw32q
cwd: /private/var/folders/86/rclj3l7x7jg9fz8pxnwqx3fw0000gn/T/pip-install-y6w6o5s6/zs_df7e592a69884a79a9c736d8120cade7/
Complete output (**244** lines):..

ecc ecc...

I tried to follow the different **Questions** on stackOverflow but no **Answers** seem to work.
I have seen:
[Command errored out with exit status 1 on mac while installing odoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64836894/command-errored-out-with-exit-status-1-on-mac-while-installing-odoo)
ant others...

I'm using a Mac with chip M1, but I also tried with Ubuntu, getting the same errors, maybe with some error less.
it seems like the library doesn't work anymore.

i have gcc pack, Xcode for Mac.

some of the errors at the end:

zs/_zs.c:5658:19: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
*tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
^~~~~~~~~~~~~
curexc_traceback
/Users/lorenzodigianvittorio/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8/cpython/pystate.h:81:15: note: 'curexc_traceback' declared here
PyObject *curexc_traceback;
^
zs/_zs.c:5670:24: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _ts'
tmp_type = tstate->exc_type;
~~~~~~  ^
zs/_zs.c:5671:25: error: no member named 'exc_value' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
tmp_value = tstate->exc_value;
^~~~~~~~~
curexc_value
/Users/lorenzodigianvittorio/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8/cpython/pystate.h:80:15: note: 'curexc_value' declared here
PyObject *curexc_value;
^
zs/_zs.c:5672:22: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
tmp_tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
^~~~~~~~~~~~~

Answer (score 0):

The error "*no member named 'exc_traceback' in 'struct _ts'*" means the package is incompatible with Python 3.7+. Let's see: https://pypi.org/project/zs/0.10.0/ Latest release was at May 9, 2014. Perhaps the package is too old. Try it with Python 3.6.